# Uploading an image to a specific Facebook Album

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am having trouble using permissions to upload to a specific Facebook album.

I am set to an admin to a specific Facebook page, however whenever I try to upload a photo I cannot seem to get access to do it.

The error I get is:

> Fatal error: Uncaught OAuthException: (#120) Invalid album id thrown

If I explore using the Graph explorer, I can see this album without any access token required.

The URL I am using is https://graph.facebook.com/albumId/photos

The album I am trying to upload is an album within a Facebook page, which I created within Facebook.

The permissions I have set are:

- user_photos
- friends_photos
- publish_actions
- manage_pages
- publish_stream
- photo_upload

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, check if the user is logged in:

```
function getLoginStatus() {  
            FB.getLoginStatus(function (response) {
                if (response.status === 'connected') {
                    // the user is logged in and connected to your
                    // app, and response.authResponse supplies
                    // the user's ID, a valid access token, a signed
                    // request, and the time the access token 
                    // and signed request each expire
                    var uid = response.authResponse.userID;
                    var accessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken;

                    getPageAccess();

                } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
                    // the user is logged in to Facebook, 
                    //but not connected to the app
                    logIn();
                } else {
                    // the user isn't even logged in to Facebook.
                    logIn();
                }
            });
        }
```

Then get the **page** access token associated to the user:

```
function getPageAccess() {               
            FB.api('/PAGE_ID?fields=access_token', function (resp) {
                var pageAccessToken = resp.access_token;
            });
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

This seems a common issue. If you want to impersonate Facebook Page (that is, act as page itself for uploading, posting and sharing) you have to first obtain an access token for that page:

1. Issue a GET Request to '/me/accounts' using user access token
2. Loop the result set and look for the page (**pay attention** to category property of each item, skip "application" as it's considered an account)
3. Store `access token` for that page.

Then (using PHP SDK):

```
$page    = '432652662'; // Your page id
$album   = '128949205'; // Your album id
$source  = 'mypic.png'; 
$payload = array('source' => '@' . $source,
    'access_token' => 'page access token');

// Upload photo for specific page and album
$sdk->api("/$page/$album/photos", 'POST', $payload);
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think I have found the solution.

If you go to https://graph.facebook.com/me/accounts

Each account will have its own access_token. When uploading an image to a Facebook page, you will need to pass that access_token as a parameter.